# save data from 2 forms and show it in a 3rd form c# 

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm workingin Visual Studio 2008, C# framework 3.5, I have 3 forms, 
  in form1 and form2 I read some data (contains in a gridview in each form) and pass it to
  form3, but when I try to save data (in form3)I just get the data from form1 or form2, but
  not both 
  I THINK THE PROBLEM IS IN THE LOAD PAGE, thanks in advance, here is my code:

```
    //form3:

public partial class menu2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    lblNombreUsuario.Text = (string)Session["sesionicontrol"];
    //prueba
    if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            txtRutEncuestador.Text = Request.QueryString["rut"].ToString();
            leerNombre();
        }
        catch { };
    }

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
        {
            try
            {

                txtIdEstudio.Text = Request.QueryString["cod_sap"].ToString();
                leerEstudios();

            }
            catch { };

        }
    }
```

Comment: -1 You need to condense you down to show what exactly your having problems with, not just post the whole lot and expect someone to trawl through it all

Comment: Please narrow down your code to where you think the problem is

Comment: However, why don't you use just a single form?

Comment: @JaneDoe I think the problem is in load page, because read the data but doen't keep the data from form1 if I try to pass the data from form2, thanks.

Comment: All i see that you are doing is populating a grid in both page1 and page2 and redirecting the row selection to the menu2 page. I did not see where you were populating the "sessioncontrol" so that is probably null and cannot be cast to string.

Comment: @AlexMendez the sessioncontrol works fine, and as you said, I'm tryng to redirecting the row selection in menu2 page, I can do it separatly but cannot save both.thanks for your fast reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your original posted code all i see that you are doing is populating a grid in both page1 and page2 and redirecting the row selection to the menu2 page. I did not see where you were populating the "sessioncontrol" so that is probably null and cannot be cast to string. Also, doing empty try catch is bad coding practice. You should do the following instead:

```
lblNombreUsuario.Text = (string)Session["sesionicontrol"];
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    //prueba 
    if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
    {
        if Request.QueryString["rut"] != null)
        {
            txtRutEncuestador.Text = Request.QueryString["rut"].ToString();
            leerNombre();
        }

        if (Request.QueryString["cod_sap"] != null)
        {
            txtIdEstudio.Text = Request.QueryString["cod_sap"].ToString();
            leerEstudios();
        }
    } 
}
```

If you want to have both in one page, you will need a query that ruturns both and then on selection do: (Using sudo code here)

```
Request.Redirect("~/Menu2.aspx?rut=" + rut + "&code_sap=" + codeSap);
```

Comment: thanks for your help and advice (about try catch) with your code I can read the data but if read the data from form1, I "lost" the data from form2, but thanks anyway. :)

Comment: I set your answer as accepted because I can save now the data, but I have a strange behavior because read additional data, I'll keep coding, must be the row position, so, thanks again for your help.

Comment: Tim B James, jonsca, PaulG, RegDwight, PeeHaa how you can say that is not a real question if somebody answered (alex mendez), you must understand that not all people who use this site speak english, and besides are beginners, you must advice about the faqs, of course but you must understand that a lot of people can't write the question as you want, you are not understanding we are begginers